# How to convert Place Picker Documentation code in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3

**Place Picker**

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251)
  let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
  let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
  let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
  let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
  placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

  placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return
    }

    if let place = place {
      print("Place name \(place.name)")
      print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
      print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
    } else {
      print("No place selected")
    }
  })
}
```

[Place Picker in Swift 2 in Doucmentation of Google Map](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker)

While converting in Swift 3

```
   placePicker?.pickPlace(callback: { (place: GMSPlace!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let place = place {

}
        } as! GMSPlaceResultCallback)
```

And gives Bad Instruction access Error

Comment: what error you are facing when you are using this in Swift 3 ?

Comment: } as! GMSPlaceResultCallback)

Comment: This wants me to convert the callback and when i run it it gives Bad Instriction access error

Comment: Convert your callBack section to "callback: { (place, err) -> Void in" and Delete "as! GMSPlaceResultCallback)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
placePicker.pickPlace(callback: { (place, err) -> Void in {

if let error = error {
print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
return
}

if let place = place {
print("Place name \(place.name)")
} else {
print("No place details for \(placeID)")
}
})
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSPlaceTableViewCell setTypeIcon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe919ac2800'

Comment: Great. If it helps you solve your error, please accept it as answer so it can be helpful for others. For Other error Can you post the diff question and code for "GMSPlaceTableViewCell" so we can check what went wrong